# Как мне сделать проверку на то что аккаунт есть в таблице, и если да то как мне узнать его пароль?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Я новичок в MySQL, и не очень понимаю как мне проверить есть ли в таблице аккаунт и если да то какой у него пароль. Я делаю игру в которой я сохраняю данные(монетки, друзья и тд) в аккаунте.
Если даже читаю про EXISTS и про то как узнать пароль в таблице(я этого не нашел или плохо искал).
Игру пишу на PHP точнее в студии DevelNext.

Comment: Если из таблицы пользователей можно узнать пароль, то это прямо оооочень огромная дыра в безопасности. Скажите что за игра, что бы я не вздумал в неё играть

Comment: *как мне проверить есть ли в таблице аккаунт и если да то какой у него пароль.* Запросить пароль для аккаунта. Если аккаунт есть - вернётся пароль (или пароли, если аккаунт не уникален), иначе пустой набор записей.

Comment: Во-первых, как писали выше, пароли стоит хранить только в захешированном виде (md5 или sha1 вам в помощь) и, для того чтобы понять, подходит ли пароль, достаточно то что вводит юзер тоже захешировать тем же способом и сравнить эти два значения, во-вторых, для проверки существует ли аккаунт, достаточно запросить юзернейм, и если он храниться у вас в таблице (а он должен), то ищете по нему. Что-то типа SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name = 'Petro' - если ничего не вернуло юзера нет.

Comment: @ДаниилШрамков У меня была идея хешировать пароли юзеров которые зарегистировались, только мне нужно узнать пароль(хешированный) юзера. Про то что есть ли он в таблеце - за это спасибо.

Comment: Ну а конкретно пароль: SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Name = 'name'

Comment: @Даниил Шрамков хранить пароли захешированные в md5 или sha1 в 2021 - это почти такая же дыра, как хранить их в открытом виде.

Comment: Ну если проект серьёзный, то конечно нужно более надежные способы. Можно два раза захешировать, соль добавить)